# RestSharp AddHeader not working

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am building a simple REST/Json windows client using C# and RestSharp 105.2.3.  Everything is working beautifully but the additional HTTP header I am specifying does not seem to being added according to the Wireshark trace.  Am I missing something or is there an underlying HTTP method I should use?

The code is straightforward as outlined below and I cannot see the RequestId header in the trace:

```
    var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("username", password");

    var requestParams = new RequestItem
    { Parameter1 = "test1", Parameter2 = "test2" };

    var request = new RestRequest("/sample/", Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("RequestId", "value");

    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.Parameters.Clear();
    var requestParamsJson = request.JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestParams);
    request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", requestParamsJson, ParameterType.RequestBody);
    IRestResponse<ResponseItem> response = client.Execute<ResponseItem>(request);
```

Comment: I think its the `request.Parameters.Clear();` call.  Looking at the source code, `AddHeader` adds an item to the `Parameters` collection, which you're then clearing.

Comment: Thats it!!! I thought to Parameters.Clear method only affected Parameters and the Content.

Comment: Well hot diggity.  I'll add it as an answer then.

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the `request.Parameters.Clear();` call.  [Internally](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/e7c65df751427298cb59f5456bbf1f59967996be/RestSharp/RestRequest.cs#L479), RestSharp adds headers to the `Parameters` collection, which you're clearing.  So removing the call, or moving it above where you add the header, will fix the issue.